# How to set DNS entry with no domain in local network?

Tags: linux, windows, dns, domain

I would like to refer local network computers with short DNS names, without full multilevel path. What is required for it?

Probably I need to know terminology or something.

I wish to configure both windows and linux machines for it.

**UPDATE**

I need centralized solution, not to edit hosts file on each computer.

Comment: is [.local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) what you are looking for?

Comment: I have added entyr "bugzilla.local" to my DNS forwarder, but this didn't help. I can ping `bugzilla.local` now, but no `bugzilla`.

Comment: What are you using for local DNS? Why would you expect to be able to drop .local along the way?

Comment: I am using DNS forwarder from `pfsense`. I can set up any other service. I don't "expect" I can omit "local", I "wish" I could omit everything, except computer name. It is possible with "hosts" file, why isn't it possible with DNS?

Comment: This is probably what you want. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275553

Comment: Idk about Windows...but on Linux, you can add `search <mycustomtld>` to _/etc/resolv.conf_, and then you can `ping bugzilla.<mycustomtld>` as `ping bugzilla`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have no DNS role holding server on the network you're only option is to edit the 'hosts' file on every windows and linux machine you have.

under Windows:

`c:\Windows\system 32\drivers\etc\hosts` (edit it with admin privileges notepad)

under Linux:

`\etc\hosts` (edit it with sudo privileges)

But of course it would be simpler to install DNS role somewhere

Regards

Ahmad

Comment: This can also easily be centralized by putting a script on each server which downloads the host file for that machine to the correct location from a centralized location. Put that script on a cronjob\scheduled task and every machine will update when you make changes. I'd also make it just exit if the files hasn't been modified so that you can run it fairly frequently (so that updates happen quickly). I use this setup for my ad hoc VM networks because it is very simple to make changes and setup.